# Wordpress Plug-in - Trigger e-mail based on a specific date

Tags: wordpress, email, plugins, newsletter, contact-form-7

I currently have a registration form for people to signup and pick a date for an "appointment". They get sent an e-mail right after filling it up with the details. I need another e-mail to be sent a day before their chosen date to remind them, but that can't be fulfilled by plugins I currently have.

Does anyone know of any Wordpress plug-in that allows the sending of an e-mail message (with a template and user specific data) based on a specified date?

Any piece of information or advice would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How I would approach this would be with Wordpresses event scheduling. When a user submits the form to schedule their appointment, set a new action for the reminder email:

```
// Set this when you send the confirmation email
// Set the $unix_timestamp to be whenever you want the reminder to be sent.
// Args can be an array of the data you will need. Such as the users email/appt date
$args = array(
 'email' => 'email@email.com'
);
wp_schedule_single_event($unix_timestamp, 'set_reminder', $args);
```

Now we have to catch that, and create a function to actually create and send the email (assuming you use a similar process):

```
add_action('set_reminder','do_reminder');

function do_reminder($args) {
// $email = $args['email'], etc.
// send reminder email.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Wysija Newsletters. You http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wysija-newsletters/. You can use template and user specific data in your email with this plugin.

Comment: Already checked wysija and asked there as well. They can't do an e-mail triggered by dates as of the moment.

Comment: Ok. I'll let you know if I find some other.

Comment: No problem, I highly appreciate your response. Thanks for taking the time! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with writing your own code(I guess you are more or less ok with that), you can use the WordPress Schedule API(okay, maybe that's not the official name, but it works). Basically it's kind of a cron-job, but for WordPress. It has one downside though - it will only trigger on time, if WordPress is rendered(in other words accessed, so that it's code will execute). That can be easily fixed by adding a simple cron-job to your hosting account, that will simply access your home page every X hours.

You can find useful information on the API [here](http://wordpressapi.com/2010/02/07/schedule-events-wordpress/).

Basically what you should have inside of your scheduled function is to get the records of people that should be sent reminder emails(you should probably store additional information about whether a reminder email has been sent or not) and send them the emails. I don't know what is the way you're storing the information from the registration form, but if you are using a Custom Post Type, then things should be pretty easy for you.

Comment: Looks promising albeit a bit tedious if there already is an existing plugin. I'll keep looking but if I don't get lucky I'll have to write one. Thanks for your reply, really appreciate it! :)

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit tricky, so if you do find a plugin that will do what you need, you might want to use it.